# how to customize font colour and background colur in rich text box in salesforce UI side

Tags: customization, richtextarea

I want to show some text with background and text color, if it is possible through rich text box , then how to set background color and text color, if it's not, then which way i should go ?(trigger/ajax or something else)

I want to apply this settings on custom field of a object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rich text fields store HTML in the backend, so if you save in some relevant HTML that includes some div/spans with some CSS in style attributes you should see the colours on screen.

e.g. store the following HTML into a rich text field (written in via code or some other means, not in the editor itself).

```
<span style="display: inline-block; background-color: #00f; color: #fff;">Hello, World!</span>
```

Of course, if you're just talking about displaying text on a Visualforce page there's no reason why you can't just use regular CSS techniques.

Comment: I want to apply this settings on custom field of a object. In visualforce, its fine.but on salesforce side its difficult.

Comment: I am passing this <span> using trigger, so after insert or update of that field , it reflect back as background color and text color. thanks @lacey